# Selenium webdriver for handling dynamic ckeditors

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently doing scraping using selenium in java for a website. Most of the pages I scrap contains `ckeditor`. I am currently using javascript to get the data from ckeditor using javascriptexecutor executescript method

`CKEDITOR.instances['locator name/id/class'].getData()`

but the problem here is the locator is changing dynamically  I also found a way to get the name of the locator by `getAttribute(name)` method and used it in javascript but the problem here is some `ckeditors` use id , some use names or classes and mostly all the attributes(id,class,name) are used in html

Sample html

```
<textarea id="cm_ckeditor name="profile_description" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; visibility: hidden; display: none;"></textarea>
```

here if i use `CKEDITOR.instances['profile_description'].getData()` it is failing

It returns the data correctly when I use   `CKEDITOR.instances['cm_ckeditor'].getData()` similarly there  are scenarios in which the name works and id fails

Comment: So ... do you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question i guess you want to get data from ckeditor whose locator is changing dynamically

```
    var myinstances = [];

    for(var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {

    CKEDITOR.instances[i]; 

    CKEDITOR.instances[i].name;

    CKEDITOR.instances[i].value;  

    CKEDITOR.instances[i].updateElement();

    myinstances[CKEDITOR.instances[i].name] = CKEDITOR.instances[i].getData(); 

    return myinstances[CKEDITOR.instances[i].name];

}
```

You can use this javascript inside javascript executor

```
 JavaScriptExecutor js=(JavaScriptExecutor) driver;

 String ckeditor_data=(String) js.executeScript("function getdata(){var myinstances = []; for(var i in CKEDITOR.instances) { CKEDITOR.instances[i]; CKEDITOR.instances[i].name; CKEDITOR.instances[i].value;CKEDITOR.instances[i].updateElement(); myinstances[CKEDITOR.instances[i].name] = CKEDITOR.instances[i].getData(); return myinstances[CKEDITOR.instances[i].name];}}if ( CKEDITOR.status == 'loaded' ) {getdata();}");

 System.out.println(ckeditor_data);
```

Hope this helps you...kindly get back if you have any queries